# google doc to pdf convertion with GAS disregards text edits

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'am creating a google app script that generates invoices based on data in a spreadsheet. For every invoice, the script should copy a template doc-file, add the relevant data and output a pdf.

When I try to export the modified doc-file to pdf, it creates a pdf based on the original template file. None of the edits have been taken into account.

Yet, in my `convertToPDF` function, the file ID is the right one and the doc it points to has been properly modified. I tried to call `convertToPDF` from outside `GenInvoice` but with little success.

My understanding of GAS is limited, I'm merely tinkering my way forward through trial and error. Here, I am clueless.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces my issue:

```
function GenInvoice(folder, month, restaurant, adresse, forfait, invoiceNr){

  // copy template
  var templateid = "1kDDBHiwUikKHRtywJ_Tfig4Nf_wNbdy814_5SvLerkw" 
  var template = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid);
  var newfile  = template.makeCopy(template.getName() + "_edited" );

  // Open invoice in docs
  var docId  = newfile.getId()
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // Remplacing place-holders
  body.replaceText("%TemplateText%", "%ModifiedText%");

  // Final print
  body.appendParagraph('Great work! Keep your flow!');

  // convert to PDF
  convertToPDF(docId)
}

function convertToPDF(theId){
  console.log(theId)
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(theId);

  /* Add the PDF extension */
  docblob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName("Modified_template.pdf"); // doc.getName() + ".pdf")

  var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "doc.saveAndClose();" before converting.

Like that:

```
// Final print
body.appendParagraph('Great work! Keep your flow!');

//Save and close doc
doc.saveAndClose();

// convert to PDF
convertToPDF(docId)
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, it solved the problem. I suspected that the file should be closed but did not know about `doc.saveAndClose();`